# Do any modern filesystems support arbitrary metadata handling?

Tags: linux, filesystems, metadata

My overall goal is to help people in my organisation find more relevant unstructured data. Files are currently stored on NT drives, multiple SharePoint vintages, Linux disks. Various open and proprietary file formats, some support metadata, many don't.

I need tools that can interrogate files for metadata - some work needed here. I also need something that can crawl and index the metadata, and put it in context - again, further work needed.

However, having generated some metadata for a file, I'd like to attach it to the file inside the filesystem, so that it always remains with the file - not a hidden file or anything like that, but a deeper association within the file system. Do any file systems (preferably Linux) support this kind of feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's called [extended attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes), and most native filesystems on linux supports it.

You can manipulate these attributes with the [getfattr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getfattr)/[setfattr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfattr) commands, and there's a corresponding [C API](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getxattr) for doing the same.

Comment: That looks interesting, though I was thinking more about how metadata I had generated might be linked to the file. Stuff like AcoustID for audio, for example. It would aways be there for some other software to make relational sense of?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really asking now. If you want to "link"  AcoustID to an audio file, sure, you can set an AcoustID attribute on a file and give it a certain value (e.g. with the command `setfattr -n user.AcoustID -v 99 myfile.mp3`) Any software can read that from the file again and make use of it, as long as that software is programmed to do that. Albeit, I'm not sure all distros enables the extended attributes by default - you might need special mount options to do this...